# How do I Recover from severe over-clocking

Tags: overclocking

My problem first appeared to me as a video failure when the laptop LCD would not turn on at boot-up and  neither the VGA nor the HDMI port would output a video signal.

Sony Vaio Laptop VPCZ13JGX Windows 7 64 bit

I know the laptop is/was working after the display failed because I was able to login (without a display) and heard the Windows startup music.

I had tried debugging suggestions offered in other forums such as resetting the BIOS, re-seating the RAM, checking the power adapter, trying other video ports, etc. but nothing was working.

There were two Key symptoms I had noticed which led me to believe it was an over-clocking issue.

The fan was blowing out abnormally hot air only seconds after startup.

The time between login to hearing the Windows startup music was clearly much quicker than normal.

Without going into details, let me just say that their is a party with access to the laptop and with a motive for doing this. I only bring it up so that you know that over-clocking is a reasonable possibility without my knowledge and I don't want the discussion to get sidetracked.

My reasoning for believing the processors were over-clocked follows:

It runs very hot only seconds after start-up. Normally it would only be that hot if running with a fully loaded CPU for some period of time. I'm also fairly certain that it ran that hot prior to resetting the Bios and I had a password set for accessing the boot drive setup through the bios.

Running hot due to software or malware creating an extra load on the processors doesn't seem possible before Windows login and certainly not before access to the boot drive has been granted.

An over-clocked CPU could explain the the hot start-up

An over-clocked CPU could explain the accelerated loading of the OS.

An over-clocked GPU could explain the failure of the video output.

GPU failure with the CPU still working seems reasonable to me given the large heat sink on the CPU.

I have no experience with over-clocking processors other than what I've recently read, so I could really use some help to do my own repairs if possible. Please bear in mind that I'm on a limited budget. I require Windows 7 for some custom software I created and still need so I don't think there is a huge advantage to owning a new cheaper model laptop over salvageing the old one. Besides, I can't guarantee that the same thing couldn't be repeated on a new laptop which is a risk I can't afford.

Any ideas on how I could reverse the over-clocking? Given the following:

The laptop has no video output.

I have previously disabled remote access to the laptop as well as Bluetooth and WiFi. There may be Wi-Max drivers installed if that gives anyone any ideas for accessing the laptop remotely. Also there's the Gagabit Ethernet port, but I probably have the driver disabled and I'm not sure what the driver code would be to enable it from the command prompt.

I have a desktop that could access the laptop SSD boot drive as a non-boot drive if that helps.

Laptop: Windows 7 Pro, 64 bit

Desktop: Windows 7 HP, 64 bit

I'm not sure if any software used would still be installed or if it could have been uninstalled it prior to shutdown. Does anyone know what I would search for to find any software used for over-clocking?

If I replaced the graphics card, would it run at factory settings or still be in an over-clocked state?

Where are those settings stored? It doesn't seem to be the hard drive, since a boot from DVD didn't help. Also I believe I reset the BIOS but, again, I don't know how to verify that.

Should I assume the graphics card is a loss or is it possible that some kind of safeguard could have disabled the card before any damage was done?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Most OEM products cannot be overclocked.   What makes you think your laptop was overclocked?  You indicate not to bring it up but it, you specifically, gave this a title which mentions it.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: a severe overclock, causing huge problems wouldnt be booting behind the scenes , of the video not initing proper. it instead would be crashing before playing a startup sound.  so it is unlikely that a cpu overclock is the cause of not being able to see.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq as I stated, it was the only way to explain the hot startup before anything could be putting a load on the CPU.

Comment: @Psycogeek are you saying that the PC couldn't boot up to Windows without a graphics card? As I stated, I believe it's a GPU failure while the CPU is running over-clocked. Isn't this possible? Don't most MBs have their own graphics circuitry?

Comment: A PC can boot without a grafics card, servers boot all the time with no view.  You were talking about a laptop, soo i am not understanding the grafics card referance?  (that is confusing as if it was a desktop?)  A laptop would have both GPU items on the mainboard (Integrated), or a daughterboard (often for dedicated gpu).

Comment: Well, it's true that I'm more familiar with desktops. However I was under the impression that a graphics card could be replaced in a laptop so I assumed it was a daughter card to the MB.

Comment: at any rate, assume it was OCed (not likely), resetting the bios on even the highest end overclocking computer should set it back to safer defaults.  Resetting would also return any wildly odd settings that might stop the view, leaving you with the real problem still.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I was wondering how those settings were saved. It's possible that I never reset the bios as I don't know how I could verify this. On a desktop I'd use the reset jumper. I tried to disconnect what I thought was the battery for a few minutes but even that wasn't the silver disk battery I'm used to seeing. It looked like an old style electrolytic capacitor that was connected to the MB by two wires and a small Molex connector. Who'd that cause the Bios to reset? Could I have disconnected the wrong component?

Comment: One would assume that information is in the manuel or on the web somewhere.  there is usually a lithium coin battery in even most lappies. cant be sure yours has one, but it is likely.  they often also have at least "pads" to do a reset (if not jumpers)..

Comment: I suppose it could be located on the back of the MB which is difficult to access. I saw another post asking where to locate the battery on the same model and he couldn't get any help through Sony so I didn't follow through with Sony assuming it was a security issue. I did find a battery that Sony does use that looked similar to the one I disconnected however. I looked for contact pads as well but didn't see any. There was a pattern of pads that didn't have any markings, But I didn't see any connections, even through something like an embedded blind via.

Comment: Most laptops have a GPU that is soldered onto the motherboard.  In most cases it is not possible for the end user to replace this GPU for several reasons ( Costs, Lack of Equipment, Skill Involved ) there are exceptions to this rule of course.  Lets just assume because its a Sony laptop, which isn't the best brand for customization, that the GPU cannot be replaced.  Feel free to provide the service manual to us that says otherwise though.

Comment: @Ramhound, thanks, I'll try to see if I can find any documentation. It's a bit disheartening news though :(

Comment: Ramhound is correct. You cannot replace the GPU on most laptops, including this one.

Comment: You should describe better the circumstances around and before the moment you noticed these issues (in the case of the OC hypothesis being false). Regarding the possibility of other sorts of tampering, as you already opened the laptop, you probably also checked for foreign objects on the main board/inside the case, right? If a clever "prank" is to be expected and there has been plenty of time to perform it, something could have been added so that it drains large current but doesn't cause a complete short circuit. This could also explain the immediate heating (but not the quickening of boot).

Comment: @zagrimsan, It's been some time since I first noticed the problem as I've been trying to resolve it while working on many other issues at the same time. The problem just seemed to come up when I tried to start my laptop so I can't put it in the context of what I was working on when it failed. Besides that, I am working on multiple computers so it's just too difficult for me to nail down details about the last session on my laptop. Let's just say that circumstances beyond my control have made my life extremely complicated this past year.

Comment: I should add, to answer some of your other comments. I don't think it's possible for someone to have had prolonged physical access to my laptop. Also I've opened my laptop case several times since it happened and something like a piece of metal shorting out components isn't something that would have been able to go by unnoticed.

Comment: If physical (electronical) tampering is out of the question, I'd be willing to bet on a device malfunction, too. The OC hypothesis is just too unlikely at this point.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is your graphics card or monitor died, and I doubt it has something to do with overclocking. 99,9% of laptops are not overclockable, maybe some gamer models, but then again you can't kill it that easily as it has it's limits and strict thermal control.

Hot startup is probably caused by:

1. Cooling problems
2. Shorted out or otherwise faulty GPU (or some other non-critical component)
3. Bad battery

Now you said you hear Windows start up and I assume you can access your account. If this is the case you can attempt enabling a network interface and connecting to a network and starting something like [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com), as it will be simpler than setting up remote access.

To help you trough setup, get another Windows 7 computer and work in parallel on both. Enable Windows Narrator by pressing Win + Enter keys on both computers and go from there. It will help you navigate blindfolded.

After you get access to your computer you can check device manager for anything out of place, check CPU/GPU clocks and post back what you found so we can work from there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I'm sure I had disabled the Ethernet driver and I don't know the driver code for enabling it via an elevated command prompt. :(

Comment: You can re-enable it, Narrator will help you aim your mouse in the dark, that's why I suggested using two computers so you can see and hear on one, and try and replicate that on your laptop using only hearing.

Comment: Cool, so does it work by hovering the mouse over a word in the driver window?

Comment: Easier would be to buy a USB graphics adapter.

Comment: Yes, It works on my Windows 10, but I see no reason not to work on Windows 7, Narrator is an old peace of software.

Comment: @ qasdfdsaq, now that sounds promising. Do you know if that would be plug-n-play I hope.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq You may need to install drivers for it and/or select it as default device if the one in laptop is not totally gone, but it's an option of course.

Comment: @EnisP.Aginić: True, though there's a global shortcut to switch to it (Win+P) plus closing the lid usually deactivates the built-in screen. Drivers... more of an issue. Not entirely sure if some can be used without them.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I could print out screenshots to help things along

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Not sure, but I think Win + P will only change monitors, not GPUs, drivers manage which GPU is outputing to displays.

Comment: @TakenItEasy Give it a go, It shouldn't be that hard, if you use only keyboard it will probably be even easier (alt + Tab to switch window, tab to navigate inside window, and most keyboards have right click key)

Comment: @Enis, ok thanks. It just sounds daunting but navigating with the keyboard makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all of the help. I need to get some sleep before attempting this so I'll start working on it when I get up.

Comment: @EnisP.Aginić: Win+P changes monitors, GPU is irrelevant. Drivers don't manage anything.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Control panel on mine says "Preferred GPU - Auto", with options to choose integrated graphics, high performance GPU and auto. It must manage it somehow, as my monitor in connected via single cable.

Comment: @EnisP.Aginić: You're talking about a special case of Optimus technology, which is irrelevant because it does not apply to USB adapters. Optimus only works with two GPUs that are specifically hard-wired together for the purpose.

Comment: I found this: "Plugable USB 2.0 to 1920 VGA/DVI/HDMI Video Graphics Adapter (UGA-165)" that claims to be plug-n-play which would be awesome. Don't know how to add a link here but I found it through Google shopping and it's listed in blinq.com. "Plugable" is the brand name. Since it says graphics adapter, I couldn't tell if it was still relying on the laptops GPU or not. It said that it used the display link DL-165 chipset. Sorry, I'm ignorant about these things.

Comment: @TakenItEasy: The whole point of a USB adapter is that it does not rely on the laptops GPU. How can it rely on a GPU it isn't even connected to?

Comment: @qasdfdsaq, I wasn't sure how they did it but I think it's explained some where on their website. Anyway, I contacted them directly and they confirmed that it requires the internal GPU. There are other devices that say explicitly that they are external graphic cards, but non of them that I've checked with can auto-load drivers for Windows 7 The last bit of news, I've tried to logon again but I can't get the logon to work despite trying every combination of passwords for every condition I could think it could be in. For all I know maybe I triggered a BSOD at some point working in the dark?